# try to program calculator in python 3

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been trying to program a simple calculator using tkinter but I am having trouble printing the text from my buttons to my label. So far I have only tried experimenting with the number 0.

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('500x750')  
root.title('Scientific Calculator')

def labelChange():
    labelframe.config(text = "")

# top label where input is displayed

labelframe = LabelFrame(root, textvariable=labelChange)
labelframe.pack(fill="both", expand="yes")


# creating our buttons for number input, decimal and operators
# these  buttons will be placed in bottom frame horizontally 

bottom_frame = Frame(root, height = 100, width = 500)
bottom_frame.pack_propagate(0)

button_eq = Button(bottom_frame, text = '=')  
button_eq.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=TRUE, fill='both')

button_dec = Button(bottom_frame, text = '.')  
button_dec.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=TRUE, fill='both')

button_0 = Button(bottom_frame, text = '0', command=labelChange)  
button_0.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=TRUE, fill='both') 

button_negpos = Button(bottom_frame, text = '+/-')  
button_negpos.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=TRUE, fill='both')

bottom_frame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: why are you using a `LabelFrame` instead of `Label`?

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x750')
root.title('Scientific Calculator')

def labelChange():
    labelframe.config(text=labelframe["text"] + button_0["text"])

# top label where input is displayed

labelframe = LabelFrame(root, text="default")
labelframe.pack(fill="both", expand="yes")


# creating our buttons for number input, decimal and operators
# these  buttons will be placed in bottom frame horizontally

bottom_frame = Frame(root, height = 100, width = 500)
bottom_frame.pack_propagate(0)

button_eq = Button(bottom_frame, text = '=')
button_eq.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=TRUE, fill='both')

button_dec = Button(bottom_frame, text = '.')
button_dec.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=TRUE, fill='both')

button_0 = Button(bottom_frame, text = '0', command=labelChange)
button_0.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=TRUE, fill='both')

button_negpos = Button(bottom_frame, text = '+/-')
button_negpos.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=TRUE, fill='both')

bottom_frame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

root.mainloop()
```

I set the default text of `labelframe` to "default" and changed it when the `labelChange` function was called (when `button_0` was clicked). I've also replaced `textvariable` with `text` because `textvariable` should only be used when we are using a `StringVar()`. It cannot be used to call a function. I added `button_0`'s text to `labelframe`'s text as well.